# Split in pedagogy of propositional logic

Tags: logic

In some sources where I read about propositional logic, it is shown that the propositions come with a truth value baked into the sentence. In other books, it is said that the truth value a proposition take is given by "truth functions" which map from the proposition to the truth values.

Some sources which take first approach was my highschool textbook (NCERT Class-12th book), Frederic Schuller's Geometric Anatomy of Physics lectures and books which take the interpretation approach is Kleene's Logic, Modern Logic by Graeme Forbes etc

Why is there a split in the pedagogy?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you see a split: "propositions come with a truth value baked into the sentence" and "there is a function which maps each proposition to its truth value" seem to be just two slightly different ways to express the same idea. Just as "every person in this class room has a date of birth" can alternatively be expressed as "there is a function that maps every person in this class room to the date on which they were born." They are just different ways to express the same thought.

Comment: I believe that analogy is not a faithful example of the situation here. A student can not be in the classroom without being born, however according to one of the approach mentioned in question body, a preposition can exist without ever having a truth value @JochenGlueck

Comment: Well, if you have a "truth function" which is defined on the set of all propositions, then there does not exist a proposition without a truth value, either. I think you're really overinterpreting the situation - both approaches you describe essentially say the same thing: every proposition is either true or false. If one calls this a "truth function" or claims that the truth value were somehow inherent to the proposition, is just cosmetics - it doesn't effect in any way how one actually works with logical propositions in most parts of mathematics.

Comment: I still disagree. If we take "truth value is inherent to preposition" approach then I believe it would be harder to see how something like Fuzzy Logic would come about. If you would start from the prespective that the truth of statement is independent of the statement then it would be intuitive that statements can take values other than true or false. Also this has implications when translating back and forth from Natural Language to Formal. For eg, according to Frege sentence has two semantic aspects: A sense and a reference, and, a sentence without a reference cant be assigned T/F

Comment: [See here for instance](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_reference) @JochenGlueck

Comment: I'm increasingly under the impression that the "split" you're preceiving is just the dinstinction between (i) the somewhat hand-wavy way to handle prositional logic in everyday maths and (iI) formal logic. in formal logic, one studies propositions as mathematical objects themselves, so one does of course need to take care to define very clearly what one is talking about. On the other hand, if one just gives a brief introduction to propositional logics such that students can use it in other mathematical subjects, [...]

Comment: [...] then saying that "every proposition has a truth value" completely captures the essence of what is going on. If one wants to do it more formally, though, one needs to write down in purely mathematical terms what it means that "every proposition has a truth value" - and this can be done by using the language of functions. That's precisely what I meant by saying "it's the same thing" - talking about a function $X \to Y$ is just the formal mathematical way to say "for every $x \in X$ one has a uniquely determined $y\in Y$". [...]

Comment: [...] These are not really different approaches - the second one is just a more formal way to write down the first one. By the way, I took a brief look at the books you mentioned. The ones by Kleene and Forbes are apparently about formal logic, so it's not surprising that the write down things more formally.

Comment: The fact that propositional logic is complete is a meta-theorem. So when we first start teaching propositional logic, we pretend that there might be propositions that are only decidable as true or false based on exhaustive analysis of truth tables, and not deduction from axioms.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think the issue you have is about mathematics education. It sounds like you are really asking a philosophical question about the nature of propositions and their truth, which is beyond the scope of this stack exchange.